# Carousel Menu on Mobile Device

Tags: usability, mobile, carousel, jquerymobile

[image]

So, I made this carousel menu as a second menu and using Jquery Mobile framework.

This carousel is clickable and when i saw on some reference there's also swipe for touchscreen. Is my carousel effective and usable for used or should i add a swipe too? because i will run it on 3 mobile devices such as iPhone, Android, and Blackberry. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is effectively asking for a review of your work.  That is not what this site is here for. You need to change it to be more generic and deal with UX principles that will be useful to other people as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the fundament parts of smart phones is swipe gestures. This is especially with photos. Where as people will understand what you've done it will feel very much like a desktop site that's been fitted onto a mobile.

There's easy enough jquery swipe plugins to use: http://stage.api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/ or http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation and the references too. But, how about the smartphone which is not use swipe gestures? such as blackberry (non-touchscreen). Probably, i should make both, swipe and the clickable too :)

Comment: You can pick up which type of mobile your using (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13831589/327074) and then if it will not have swipe then add in the buttons. Otherwise you're wasting valuable screen space for the images.